# Replace DIVs in GWT

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

I've created a simple GWT page with 5 divs which shows some info. But now I want to create a Log in page which hides all the other DIVs until the user is logged in. How can I achieve this?

I've looked at this [GWT Replace div (not append!) with RootPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338303/gwt-replace-div-not-append-with-rootpanel) but is there any other, better, way to do this?

Logged in I want the layout to be like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
     <div id="topDiv"></div>
        <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="leftDiv"></div>
                <div id="rightDiv">
                        <div id="rightDivTop"></div>
                        <div id="rightDivBot"></div>

                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

But log in screen I want like this:

```
 <div id="mainDiv">

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you study GWT Activities and Places design pattern:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

It explains how you can create multiple views/places within your application, and how a user or your application can navigate from one place (i.e. Home page) to another (i.e. Login page).

In GWT you do not replace divs. You create two or more "views". Then you show one view and hide the rest as necessary. One advantage of Activities and Places design pattern is the support for navigation history. For example, if a user goes to a Login page from a Home page, he can go back by hitting the Backspace in his browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the css of the 5 divs to be "display: none;" by default, and when the user logs in, a jquery code triggers the visability of the divs. (Asuming the login is via ajax and that you have jquery library included in your page)

***Example code:***

HTML:

```
<div class="hidden">...<div>
<div class="hidden">...<div>
...
<div class="hidden">...<div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
or:
$('.hidden').show();
```

The JQuery code should be called after logging in.

Another approach (a more secure one) would be to print out the code with php when the user is logged in (this requires a page refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

HTML/JSP

```
<div id="timeinfo" align="center"
    style="visibility: hidden;">Hello</div>
```

JAVA (after login)

```
    import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Visibility;

    RootPanel timeinfo = RootPanel.get("timeinfo");
    if (timeinfo != null) {
        timeinfo.getElement().getStyle().setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
   }
```

Comment: This hides the content, but I want to hide the div completly so that I  can have a different design on the log in screen. Any idea?

Comment: Hide top most outer `div` or you can do one more thing. get all the divs or outer div, store some where and remove it from DOM and append again after login.